# Foreign key limitations

Tags: oracle, database-design, foreign-key-relationship, plsqldeveloper

I am wondering if a PL/SQL (oracle) table can carry three foreign keys? thanks in advance if any one can help me in this regard.

Comment: Do you want to define a `ForeignKey` in a table using 3 or more keys?

Comment: You must be kidding - 3 FKs? It can have much more than that. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_constraints.htm#i1006974

Answer (score 1):

There is no explicit limit on the number of foreign keys on a table.  However, [there is a limit of 1000 columns per table](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/refrn0043.htm#REFRN0043), so that probably constitutes a practical limit.

[Here is a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bd233/1) which creates a toy table with five foreign keys.

Comment: Thanks a bunch APC, problem solved and my data base works just fine.  :)

Answer (score 0):

There is not limit on foreign keys use except logic which based behind use of foreign keys, and if one table needs too much foreign keys, which is not logic wise, and database design suffers in such scenario.
As well as 1000-column constraint of oracle tables and pl/sql procedures also have limit in code.